# Hook_theme in module not working

Tags: 7, theming

I have a ctools plugin in a module folder. I have a theme call in the .module file:

```
function vimn_article_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  dpm($path);
  return array(
      'vimn_article_template' => array(
      'template' => 'vimn_article_template',
      'path' => $path . '/templates',
      'variables' => array('title' => NULL),
    ),
  );
}
```

and then in the template file vimn_article_template.tpl.php

```
<div class="test"><div class="test" <?php print $title; ?>></div></div>
```

What am I missing here to get this to work?

The module name is vimn_article
My ctools plugin in is plugins/content_types/prevnext.inc
my template file is located in vimn_article/templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only defining the function, your not calling it.

```
   print theme('vimn_article_template', $vars);
```

Think you also have to implement hook_theme_registry_alter() for Drupal to pick up your template.

Maybe you can use a process function to assign this to a variable for the template.

```
function YOURMODULE_preprocess_HOOK($variables) {
   $output = theme('vimn_article_template', $vars);
   // etc, etc...
}
```

Comment: I put that in my .module file and get 'theme() may not be called until all modules are loaded' error

Comment: that edit didn't fix that error.

Comment: Where are you calling theme()?

Comment: the functions are in the module file.

Comment: I have a .tpl.php file called vimn_article_template.tpl.php which is in /templates folder in my module. The other code is is vimn_article.module in the module folder.

Comment: I needed to call it from my ctools plugin

Comment: Good stuff, glad you got there...